# Unable to execute mtermvectors elasticsearch query from AWS EMR cluster using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-exception

I am trying to execute this elasticsearch query via spark:

```
    POST /aa6/_mtermvectors  
    {
      "ids": [
        "ABC",
        "XYA",
        "RTE"
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "fields": [
          "attribute"
        ],
        "term_statistics": true,
        "offsets": false,
        "payloads": false,
        "positions": false
      }
    }
```

The code that I have written in Zeppelin is :

```
def createString():String = {
    return s"""_mtermvectors {
  "ids": [
    "ABC",
    "XYA",
    "RTE"
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "fields": [
      "attribute"
    ],
    "term_statistics": true,
    "offsets": false,
    "payloads": false,
    "positions": false
    }
  }"""
}

import org.elasticsearch.spark._
sc.esRDD("aa6", "?q="+createString).count
```

I get the error :

org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: parse_exception: parse_exception: Encountered " <RANGE_GOOP> "["RTE","XYA","ABC" "" at line 1, column 22.
Was expecting:
"TO" ...

```
{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"_mtermvectors {\"ids\": [\"RTE\",\"ABC\",\"XYA\"], \"parameters\": {\"fields\": [\"attribute\"], \"term_statistics\": true, \"offsets\": false, \"payloads\": false, \"positions\": false } }"}}}
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:477)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:408)
```

This is probably something simple but I am unable to find a way to set the request body while making the spark call

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I don't think this is currently supported with `es-Spark` package. You can check [`this link`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/spark/core/main/scala/org/elasticsearch/spark/rdd/EsSpark.scala) to see what options are available via `sparkContext` of `esRDD`.

What you could do instead is to make use of [High Level Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html) of Elasticsearch and get the details in a List or Seq or any file and then load that into Spark RDD.

It is round the world way but unfortunately that is the only way I suppose. Just so it helps, I have created the below snippet so you at least have the required data from Elasticsearch related to the above query.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient
import org.elasticsearch.client.core.MultiTermVectorsRequest
import org.elasticsearch.client.core.TermVectorsRequest
import org.elasticsearch.client.core.TermVectorsResponse

object SampleSparkES {
  
  /**
   * Main Class where program starts
   */
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

     val termVectorsResponse = elasticRestClient
  
     println(termVectorsResponse.size)
  
   }
  
  /**
   * Scala client code to retrieve the response of mtermVectors 
   */
  def elasticRestClient : java.util.List[TermVectorsResponse] = {
    
    val client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                        RestClient.builder(
                            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")))    
    
    val tvRequestTemplate = new TermVectorsRequest("aa6","ids"); 
    tvRequestTemplate.setFields("attribute");
    
    //Set the document ids you want for collecting the term Vector information
    val ids = Array("1", "2", "3");
    val request = new MultiTermVectorsRequest(ids, tvRequestTemplate); 
    val response = client.mtermvectors(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
    
    //get the response
    val termVectorsResponse = response.getTermVectorsResponses   
    
    //close RestHighLevelClient
    client.close();    
    
    //return  List[TermVectorsResponse]
    termVectorsResponse
  }
}
```

As an example you can get the sumDocFreq of the first document in below manner

```
println(termVectorsResponse.iterator.next.getTermVectorsList.iterator.next.getFieldStatistics.getSumDocFreq)
```

All you would now need is to find a way to convert the collection into a Seq in a way that could be loaded in an RDD.